# Table 'test' was not LOCKED even though it was

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to dump some INSERT statements in a .sql 
`mysql -h "$HOST" -u "root" -D "test_db"  -e 'source test_insert.sql'`
The `test_insert.sql` makes INSERTs to a table called `test`.
Here's how the `test_insert.sql` looks like:

```
LOCK TABLES `test` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `test` ('a','b')
VALUES
    (1,2),
    .
    .
    .   

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Yet when I run this I receive the error  `ERROR 1100 (HY000) at line 3 in file: 'test_insert.sql': Table 'test' was not locked with LOCK TABLES.`

The host and connection parameters are correct, already verified that.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You should lock the `test` table also. You've acquired lock only for `address` table

`LOCK TABLES`addresses`WRITE;`

From the mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#table-lock-acquisition)

> A session that requires locks must acquire all the locks that it needs in a single LOCK TABLES statement. While the locks thus obtained are held, the session can access only the locked tables.

Comment: indeed I have locked test table. That was a mistake from my end while posting the question. I'm not sure why this doesn't work.